# System Restore is growing beyond the set limit

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

I'm running Win 7 64 bit. I manually set the System Restore slider on my C drive to 6%. The drive is a 120GB SSD - so that's 111 GB Usable. Sys Restore correctly calculates that 6% to be 6.7GB. However, when I checked it today it had climbed up to 7.33GB, even though it still shows the correct percentage and amount limit below that. See pic

[image]

I had this problem on another system and found out it was due to Avast Antivirus's additional features. See this thread
http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2434999/win-system-restore-resetting-usage-set.html

I still have Avast installed but the only things installed are File Shield, Web Shield, Browser Protection, and Software Updater.

So currently I have no idea what's causing the Sys Restore amount to increase. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: _Off-topic to your question, however, I thought it worth mentioning..._ SSDs should be configured with over-provisioning space to prevent early cell death, with OP ideally set to 10% of the drive (so your usable space should be closer to 100GB).  Generally, SSD manufacturers offer a program for their SSDs which configures the OP space at the end of the last partition.